# Python Pandas ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to learn pandas, but in line 21 it gave an error. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(10,100,75).reshape(15,5)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ["Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4","Column5",])
result = df
result = df.columns # kolonları liste şeklinde bize döndürür. Index(['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5'], dtype='object')
result = df.head(10) # ilk 10 satırın kayıtları gelir. Eğer sayı girmezsek ilk 5 satırı getirir.
result = df.tail(10) # Son 10 satırın kayıları gelir. Eğer sayı girmezsek son 5 satırı getirir.
result = df["Column1"].head() # Kolon 1' in ilk 5 satırını getirir.
result = df.Column1.head()# Yukarıdaki kodla aynı işlemi yapar.
result = df[["Column1","Column2"]].tail() # kolon 1 ve kolon 2' nin son 5 kayıtlarını getirir.
result = df[5:15][["Column1","Column2"]].head()# 5 ile 9. satırlar arasını alır.
result = df > 50 # True ve False lardan oluşan bir dataframe oluşturur.
result = df[df>50] # Koşulu sağlayan değerleri döndürür. Olmayanları ise NaN olarak döndürür.
result = df[df %2 == 0]
result = df["Column1"] > 50 # Sadece kolon 1 için koşulları kontrol eder.
result = df[df["Column1"] > 50][["Column1","Column2"]]
result = df[(df["Column1"] > 50) & (df["Column1"] <= 70)] # 1. kolon için 50 ve 70 arasındaki değerler gelir.
result = df[(df["Column1"] > 50) | (df["Column1"] <= 70)] # 1. kolon için 50 veya 70 arasındaki değerler gelir.
result == df.query("Column1 >= 50 & Column1 %2 == 0")

print(result)
```

Comment: You used `==` in your last line instead of `=`

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to compere result with the dataframe. Correct is:

```
result = df.query("Column1 >= 50 & Column1 %2 == 0")
```